# Does iOS fall back on another regional localized string?

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle, localizable.strings

An iOS app has a `Localizable.strings` file for a language with region, `es-MX` (Spanish-Mexico), but no general localization file for that language, e.g. `es` (Spanish).

Will users with device locale `es-PE` (Spanish-Peru) see the `es-MX` translation or will it fall back to the base language `en`?

Comment: Good question. I don’t know the answer to it. But t wouldn’t take long to set up an experiment to test it either way. Should only take you about an hour at most. All you need is one label and different strings for different languages.

Comment: @Fogmeister I wish someone had a reference to the docs, because testing only tells me so much. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out on the simulator with iOS 10.3 and the result is:

If an `es-MX` translation exists, but no `es` translation, then the `Localizeable.strings` for a user with locale `es-PE` fall back to the base language, in my case `en`.

If anyone has a reference to the docs please comment and I will add it to the answer. Because if the behaviour is currently not defined it may change for future iOS versions or it may even depend on the language and region. There are regions that would qualify as "parent" for other regions, e.g. `es-419` (Spanish Latin America) for `es-MX` (Spanish-Mexico), so it would be interesting how the fallback behaviour is defined.

However since `es-419` is a distinct language one can choose in the iOS settings I assume the fallback hierarchy is:

```
base
↑
|- es
   ↑
   |- es-MX
   |- es-PE
   |- es-419
   |- es-ES
```